# How to merge two dictionaries with same keys and keep values that exist in the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

For example:

```
Dictionary1={'A' :['B','C','D'],'B' :['A']}
Dictionary2={'A' :['A','B'],    'B' :['A','F']}
```

And I want this result:

```
Merge={'A' :['B'],'B' :['A']}
```

because only 'B' is in both dictionaries under 'A' and only 'B' is in both dictionaries under 'B'

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Convert the lists to sets; take the intersection; convert back to lists.

Comment: Alternately, just use a list comprehension on one list, including only the elements that are also in the other.  The tail of this looks like [x if x in B for x in A]

Comment: `{k: list(set(D1[k]) & set(D2[k])) for k in D1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def intersect(a, b):
    a, b = set(a), set(b)
    return list(a & b)


def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    return {k: intersect(v1, v2) for (k, v1), v2 in zip(d1.items(), d2.values())}


dictionary_1 = {'A' :['B','C','D'],'B' :['A']}
dictionary_2 = {'A' :['A','B'],    'B' :['A','F']}

merge = merge_dicts(dictionary_1, dictionary_2)
print(merge) # {'A': ['B'], 'B': ['A']}
```

Comment: You could use `for (k, v1), v2 in zip(d1.items(), d2.values())` to avoid multiple calls to `d1`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this form of intersection will lose the order of the values which may be a problem.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks. I was trying to find a way to avoid a second call to `d1`.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes I know. I didn't think that would've been a problem for the OP. It probably is a good idea to note that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersect(c1, c2):
    """Intersection of two iterables (e.g. lists) in the order of the first, as a list"""
    c2 = set(c2)  # for faster lookup
    return [x for x in c1 if x in c2]  # this is called a list comprehension

Dictionary1 = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['A']}
Dictionary2 = {'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': ['A', 'F']}

# Here the .keys() is purely for clarity, as iterating over a dictionary already yields its keys
Merge = {k: intersect(Dictionary1[k], Dictionary2[k]) for k in Dictionary1.keys()}

print(Merge)  # {'A': ['B'], 'B': ['A']}
```

Comment: You could probably get away with `for k in Dictionary1` as OP said they contain the same keys.

Comment: @AChampion thanks, missed that part of the spec.

Comment: mmmm I really feel like generally, `for k in d.keys()` is an anti-pattern. It's simply redundant in Python 3, and in Python 2, can cause real performance issues, making certain naive implementations polynomial time instead of linear, since searching for something `in` a list is linear vs constant in a `dict`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true, but OP is likely a beginner so I opted for maximum explicit clarity.

Comment: Can't we just use the built in set methods as well when making a function?

`def intersect(s1, s2):`
     `return set(s1).intersection(set(s2))`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy You can, but as Alex just mentioned to me, you'll lose the order of your values.

Comment: @algerbrex that is true I guess something for OP to consider if this problem increases in complexity

Comment: ana_lexi={'A': ['R', 'R', 'R', 'Y', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'Α', 'I', 'R', 'Α', 'Α', 'Y']}
 teliko={'A':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','J','U','W','X','Y','Z']}> def intersect(c1, c2):
    c2 = set(c2)  
    return [x for x in c1 if x in c2]

>>> teliko = {k: intersect(teliko[k], ana_lexi[k]) for k in teliko.keys()}
>>> print(teliko)
{'A': ['I', 'R', 'Y']}

Comment: For some reason it doesnt appear the values 'A' s even though both dictionary have A in them( first dictionary is 'ana_lexi' , second is 'teliko'

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AHidvJtR    Check it here

Comment: @AmosTheocharis you've got some weird characters in there, not normal 'A's.